# What's a good piece of LAMP-stack source code for a simple blog w/ comments?

Tags: php, web-applications, blogs, lamp

Hello I want to create a simple blog where users can post comments, but I don't really want to get into one of the heavier code generators or frameworks like Django or RoR or Wordpress. Reason is I need to learn this stuff from the inside out, given that my project will require a lot of programming "from basics" in the future (since it'll evolve into a specialist finance-oriented site with user-submittable portfolios, which is actually quite a big evolution from a blog, even if the initial structure is similar). I'm an accomplished finance/quant programmer but am fairly new to web development.

What's the best, "lean and mean" piece of source code that might get me started? Something I can easily customize to my own vision?. KISS-principle applies, but I'd like it to do basics like users and authentification and stuff ideally though.

Would prefer pure PHP and/or Python, but am open to suggestions.

Comment: Why no wordpress? It is a very simple solution to your problem. Any solution is going to require a framework of some sort, or LOTS of mundane and error prone coding.

Comment: Yeah maybe. Learning "from basics" is part of what I want to do though. Do you think Wordpress will allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want so check out [web.py](http://webpy.org/) as minimalistic 'framework' for webapplications in python. Or [sinatrarb](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) in ruby. It should give you a basic start in HTTP, URLs and request handling. Even though the latter is in ruby, the 'framework' itself consist of about 1500 lines of code and is quite readable.

On the php framework side, [symphony](http://www.symfony-project.org/) would be an option.

Comment: Thanks === this web.py does indeed look interesting. I like the "doesn't get in your way bit". I'll have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a php based blog software. 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/sphpblog/

Should work under any AMP installation.

Comment: I don't think he will ever need sphpblog, given his reason to do that. I believe it will require some database functionality

Comment: will check this out as may be a good starting point, but yes indeed, I'll need it to talk to a database for the finance and portfolios bits.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not looking for totally stand-alone code:

Incidentally, almost every available framework (at least in the PHP world) comes with a "how to create your own blog" example so you actually have a wide selection there. There are a lot of lists and questions regarding the best PHP framework on SO so I'm not opening another list. Check for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648/what-php-framework-would-you-choose-for-a-new-application-and-why), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249984/php-framework-decision-analysis-paralysis).

Be it PHP, Python or something else, you may find the tool of your choice by browsing through the respective "which framework to use?" topics on SO.

Comment: Thanks Pekka, but actually I DO want dead simple, dead easy, standalone code that I can mess with.

Answer (score 0):

I think Blosxom might meet your needs: http://www.blosxom.com/

Pretty minimalist, and provides comments, authentication, and other features via plug-ins.